# How to combine the respective children of siblings

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML

```
<entry>
<cit>
    <level type="higher">
        <part>higher1</part>
        <part>higher2</part>
    </level>
    <level type="medium">
        <combination>medium1 medium2</combination>
        <part>medium1</part>
        <part>medium2</part>
    </level>
</cit>
<cit>
    <level type="higher">
        <part>higherA</part>
        <part>higherB</part>
        <part>higherC</part>
    </level>
    <level type="medium">
        <combination>mediumA mediumB</combination>
        <part>mediumA</part>
        <part>mediumB</part>
        <part>mediumC</part>
    </level>
</cit>
</entry>
```

I now need to do a transformation (XSLT 2.0) - the desired output type is text only - that combines the (`part`-) children of the `level` element in the following way:

```
higher1 : medium1
higher2 : medium2

higherA : mediumA
higherB : mediumB
higherC : mediumC
```

The number of `part` elements in each `level` sibling is always equal, but I don't know in advance if there are 2, 3, 4 or even more `part` elements.

With the following XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="text()[not(string-length(normalize-space()))]" />
    <xsl:template match="text()[string-length(normalize-space()) > 0]">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&#xA;&#xD;', '  ')" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <xsl:for-each select="cit">
            <xsl:for-each select="level[@type='higher']">
                <xsl:value-of select="part" />
                <xsl:for-each select="./../level[@type='medium']">: <xsl:value-of select="part" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!--Trigger line break-->
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()[not(string-length(normalize-space()))]" />
    <xsl:template match="text()[string-length(normalize-space()) > 0]">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&#xA;&#xD;', '  ')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

, I only get as far as having the following output:

```
higher1 higher2: medium1 medium2
higherA higherB higherC: mediumA mediumB higherC
```

What do I need to change in order to get it right? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/entry">
    <xsl:for-each select="cit">
        <xsl:for-each select="level[@type='higher']/part">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../level[@type='medium']/part[$i]" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great, the use of a counter variable ($i) is exactly what I had been thinking of, but I was unable to code it myself! Thank you very much!

Comment: @smo Actually, in XSLT 2.0 you could do this without the variable, by using `<xsl:value-of select="../../level[@type='medium']/part[current()/position()]" />` to output the corresponding node.

Comment: @michael-hor257k Thanks for the hint, I will keep that in mind!